# Impossible to connect to local Minecraft bedrock server through Docker

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, docker

I recently installed a Minecraft Bedrock server on my synology to play with my kids.

I followed [this tutorial](https://mariushosting.com/how-to-install-minecraft-bedrock-on-your-synology-nas/).

Now, whatever I try, I get a "connection refused response from the client" on the 19132 port.

As far as I can tell I see nothing crazy in the logs :

[image]

[image]

I tried many things, including [this fix](https://superuser.com/questions/453298/how-to-force-java-to-use-ipv4-instead-ipv6), but to no avail.

Here is my complete docker setup :

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  minecraft-server:
    image: itzg/minecraft-bedrock-server
    container_name: Minecraft-Bedrock
    hostname: minecraft-server
    environment:
      TZ: Europe/London
      VERSION: LATEST
      SERVER_NAME: Minecraft Elen
      EULA: "TRUE"
      GAMEMODE: creative
      DIFFICULTY: easy
    #stdin_open: true
    #tty: true
    mem_limit: 4g
    cpu_shares: 768
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    user: 1026:100
    ports:
      - 19132:19132/udp
    volumes:
      - /volume1/docker/minecraft-bedrock/data:/data:rw
    restart: on-failure:5
```

and I'm using the default properties file.

I am a bit out of options, do you folks have any idea how I can further debug what is going wrong?

Comment: MCBE and MCJava work completely differently, they just appear similar on the surface. If you want help with MCJava servers, please ask a new question. "Minecraft Classic" was the name for some really old versions, I think there was no server software for it back then. And the new one in browsers has no multiplayer. I was about to direct you to the Minecraft wiki for help, but apparently that has no instructions for MCBE servers. Weird!

Comment: Do you really need Docker? You can just get the official program with instructions here: https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server/bedrock

Comment: Thanks @FabianRöling, it's clear from the question that I don't know much about Minecraft (yet), apologies. Let me correct the answer so I'm more precise. Yes, I do need Docker as the server will run on synology and I want auto recovery and other types of features. That being said, it's a good point to check if the issue is on the Docker side of things.

Comment: Have you checked whether port 19132 is open on your NAS? There could be some sort of firewall blocking it. I'd also recommend opening the server console (however you do that) and running a command like /list just to make sure it's running properly.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so after long investigations, I finally found what the issue was and it's simpler than I expected...

This is how the client start page looks like on my mac :

[image]

Given there was no specific item for bedrock, I just expected that Minecraft Java edition could connect to both typers of servers.

Turns out bedrock [isn't supported on Mac](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/community/posts/360076576331-Bedrock-edition-for-MacOS), plain and simple.

So it's totally expected that my Minecraft Java edition client cannot connect to the bedrock server.

Just in case someone else runs in the same thing.

What's funny is that the client does include items that aren't supported on Mac, like Minecraft dungeons ...

Anyways, case solved!

[image]